# Run a background task within controller method in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multithreading, apache-kafka

In fact, I couldn't think of a better way to phrase the question.

I have a spring-boot application. It has a certain end-point, let's say `/test`.
I make a get rest request. And the question is, can I **call some function** through **rest**, then return some response (like **204 no content**), and execute the function itself in the **background thread**?

Consider the case.

Let's say I have a method that adds a user to the database. In the method itself, the necessary fields for the entity are set and saved. But at the same time I want to run some process (functionality) in the background that would check if this user is in social networks (just a test example). Is it possible to do this without a message broker?

```
public User addUser(UserRequest request){
/* (1)
    functionality
*/
   (2)
   userRepository.save(user);


//And now, i want to start background process with socialmedia check. 
//I also want to return the user's state at the moment

(3)
//background process
socialMediaService.check(request, user);

(4)
//In fact, I would agree not to return anything. 
//It would be enough for me to return control to my controller and then to dispatcherServlet
return user;
}
```

By the way, in step (3), I could have sent a message to a message broker, like Kafka. Then another method that schedule reads kafka would perform this functionality sometime in the future.

But I'm wondering if it's possible to solve this problem without a message broker?

Answer (score 4):

I think the simplest way to implement this and stay in Spring infrastructure would be to use `@Async` - the asynchronous execution support in Spring

Simply put, annotating a method of a bean with `@Async` will make it execute in a separate thread. In other words, the caller will not wait for the completion of the called method.

First you need to put `@EnableAsync` annotation for configuration and enable Spring's asynchronous method execution capability. It should be put on your Configuration class:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class ApplicationConfig {

}
```

and after this in your service annotate your method you want to be processed asynchronously like this:

```java
// this is just an example. In your case your method check(request, user) should be annotated with @Async
@Async
public void asyncMethod() {
    ...
}
```

This should be enough to run this method asynchronously.

**Note 1:** You should know that `@Async` has some limitations:

- It must be applied to `public` methods only.
- Self-invocation — calling the async method from within the same class — won't work.

**Note 2:** By default, Spring uses a `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` to actually run these methods asynchronously. But you can define your own executor if you want to.

More details can be found [in this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async)

Comment: The ‘@Async’ goes on the definition of your socialMediaService.check(request, user) method.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the importance of that socialMedia task so you can make the right decision. Basically, with Kafka or any other message broker, you can control it better by queuing messages and process one by one for example.

If your task is quite simple and you just want to run it in background, then it's totally doable by Java's `CompletableFuture` class, which represents a potentially asynchronous operation that can be completed in the future with a result or an exception.

The concept of CompletableFuture is just like JS promise:

```java
CompletableFuture<Integer> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    // perform some time-consuming operation in background
    // it doesn't intercept the main thread
    return 42;
});

future.thenApply(result -> {
    // do something with the result
    return result * 2;
}).thenAccept(result -> {
    // do something with the final result
    System.out.println("Final result: " + result);
});
```

Comment: This worked for me. Easy and simple.